# Матрицы, классы

Tags: c++

Нужно описать класс `matricha`, в котором содержатся 3 закрытые матрицы размерности `3x3`. Открытыми методами класса являются те, которые запрашивают ввод данных в две матрицы и выводят в третью.

Сразу столкнулся с проблемой: числа выводятся в ряд. Как сделать вывод столбиком `3х3`?

Пока описал только 1 матрицу:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class matricha
{
    private:
        int A, B, C, D, E, F, G, I, J;
        int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, j;
    public:
        void get();
        void show();
};

void matricha::get()
{
    cout << "Vvedite A";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "Vvedite B";
    cin >> B;
    cout << "Vvedite C";
    cin >> C;
    cout << "Vvedite D";
    cin >> D;
    cout << "Vvedite E"; 
    cin >> E;
    cout << "Vvedite F";
    cin >> F;
    cout << "Vvedite G";
    cin >> G;
    cout << "Vvedite I";
    cin >> I;
    cout << "Vvedite J";
    cin >> j;
};

void matricha::show()
{
    cout << "" << A << endl;
    cout << "" << B << endl;
    cout << "" << C << endl;
    cout << "" << D << endl;
    cout << "" << E << endl;
    cout << "" << F << endl;
    cout << "" << G << endl;
    cout << "" << I << endl;
    cout << "" << J << endl;
};

void main()
{
    matricha one;
    one.get();
    one.show();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Что означает "выводят (данные) в третью"? И матрица, как я понимаю, это массив 3х3, а не 9 отдельных переменных.

Comment: Записывает 2 матрицы 3х3. А в третью записывается максимальные числа из 1-ой и 2-ой( они сравниваются и выбирается большое число)

Comment: Могли бы вы представить текст задания, как оно сформулировано изначально, а не как вы его описали своими словами? То, что вы написали, не имеет большого смысла.

Comment: А циклы у вас ещё не проходили?

Comment: Циклы проходили, но задание именно с классом.

Comment: Неужели класс и циклы друг друга исключают?

Comment: Описать класс матрица, в котором содержится следующие атрибуты: частные (закрытые) 3 матрицы одинаковой размерности 3х3. И методы класса (открытые), которые запрашивают ввод данных в 2 матрицы и выводят в результирующую матрицу. В результирующей матрицы содержатся максимальные элементы двух первых матриц. Отсортировать элементы главной диагонали по возрастанию

Comment: В вопрос это надо писать, а не сюда

Comment: @Андрей позновато что-то вы зачеты сдаете, сессия уже почти кончилась

Comment: Это не зачет, контрольную дали, а сессия у нас еще неделю)

Answer (score 1):

тут наброски, попробуй использовать. Но суть вопроса я не понял. Прочитали 2 массива и выводим 3й. В чем резон?

```
class matricha {

  private int[3][3][3] matrica;

  public:
    void read(int a);
    void write(int a);
}

void matricha::read(int a){
    for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
        for(int h=0; h<3; h++)
          cin >> matrica[a][k][h];
}

void matricha::write(int a){
    for(int k=0; k<3; k++) {
        for(int h=0; h<3; h++)
          cout << matrica[a][k][h] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    matricha all;
    all.read(0);
    all.read(1);
    all.write(3);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ловите

```
void matricha::show()
{
    cout << A << " " << B << " " << C << endl;
    cout << D << " " << E << " " << F << endl;
    cout << G << " " << I << " " << J << endl;
};
```

Comment: И чем вы помогли ОПу? Он со следующей домашкой прибежит снова сюда.

Comment: @ValdD может потому-что я сам сильно таким же был - придурком с пивом и телками в башке :), может он хоть чему-то научится

Comment: @Abyx считаете что ответ можно улучшить - исправте и дополните, такая у нас вроде политика с утра была

Comment: Спасибо ребят, дури в башке нет, искал я в гугле, как сделать эти чертовы столбцы, не нашел, плохо искал может. А со следующей тоже прибегу, вот только я сначала сам пытаюсь сделать, а потом спрашиваю. Я же не просил все задание делать, а описал конкретную проблему, оформление столбцов. Всем спасибо еще раз :)